# Trying to add images to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, image

I am trying to store image sources in an array and then add them into a list using javascript.

here is my code:

```
var imgSrc = new Array ("images/hangings/1.jpg","images/hangings/2.jpg");
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    $('#products ul').append('<li><img src="imgSrc[0]"/></li>');
}
```

When i load the site it displays the image boxes where i want them to be, but the images are blank. Whats wrong?/>

edit. i tried using single quotes but i got a "missing ) after argument list" error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imgSrc` needs to be called as a function, not as a string.

Also `imgSrc[0]` should be `imgSrc[i]` so that it uses the current index your looping through (not `0` every time)

```
$('#products ul').append('<li><img src="' + imgSrc[i] + '"/></li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function will literally output `<li><img src="imgSrc[0]"/></li>` for every item in your array. You also need to replace `imgSrc[0]` with `imgSrc[i]` if you want to get each respective entry instead of the first one only.

To access the content of your `imgSrc` array you must put it outside the string and concatenate. Replace your code with the following:

```
var imgSrc = new Array ("images/hangings/1.jpg","images/hangings/2.jpg");
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    $('#products ul').append('<li><img src="' + imgSrc[i] + '"/></li>');
}
```

Comment: This will return the first everytime

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve your issue:

```
$('#products ul').append('<li><img src="'+imgSrc[0]+'"/></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var imgSrc = new Array ("images/hangings/1.jpg","images/hangings/2.jpg");
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    $('#products ul').append('<li><img src="' + imgSrc[0] + '"/></li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your array..

```
$('#products ul').append('<li><img src="'+imgSrc[0]+'"/></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgSrc = new Array ("images/hangings/1.jpg","images/hangings/2.jpg");
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    $('#products ul').append('<li><img src="{0}"/></li>'.format(imgSrc[i]));
}
```